View casting of ndarray subclass
I am building a subclass of numpy ndarray - lets call it a field - where a extra information is associated to the ndarray. Within the user code, the data in the array is only significant accompanied with that extra information (which is the mesh/grid, the ndarray contains nodal values of a field on this grid).
So, as far as I am aware, the only legitimate ways for me to obtain a field is by either an explicit constructor or as a new-from-template field. Indeed, view casting implies that there would be field without a mesh, which in the context doesn't make sense. If the data of the field is treated as only data, then it is not a field anymore.
Are there reasons why I should still care about the possibility of view casting calls to my subclass?
EDIT
I note now that the (a) "unrealistic" and (b) "slightly more realistic" examples of the doc use different constructors for the basic object.
(a)
    # Create the ndarray instance of our type, given the usual
    # ndarray input arguments.  This will call the standard
    # ndarray constructor, but return an object of our type.
    # It also triggers a call to InfoArray.__array_finalize__
    obj = super().__new__(subtype, shape, dtype,
                          buffer, offset, strides, order)

(b)
     # We first cast to be our class type
    obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

So in the second case, this is a view casting afaiu. Why this change? It is not commented in the doc.
